# Html, CSS - How to display row within a row with flex css?

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I am trying to display a list of users within a row, which will be a row within a row. Apparently, my list of users are pulled from datastore using jinja2. How can I display the users vertically within the same row.

```css
$base-spacing-unit: 20px;
$half-spacing-unit: $base-spacing-unit / 2;

$color-alpha: #1772FF;
$color-form-highlight: #EEEEEE;

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    min-height:20vh;
}

.table {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid $color-form-highlight;
}

.table-header {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
    padding:($half-spacing-unit * 1.5) 0;
}

.table-row {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    padding:($half-spacing-unit * 1.5) 0;

    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background:$color-form-highlight;
    }
}

.table-data, .header__item {
    flex: 1 1 20%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!--    List dashboard form here   -->
    <h4 style="margin-top: 25px;">Your Dashboard:</h4>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-header">
                <div class="header__item"><a id="name" class="filter__link" href="#">Board name</a></div>
                <div class="header__item"><a id="wins" class="filter__link filter__link--number" href="#">Users</a></div>
                <div class="header__item"><a id="draws" class="filter__link filter__link--number" href="#">Account</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="table-content">
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-data">{{ board.tasks }}</div>
                    {% for i in board.users %}
                    <div class="table-data">{{ i }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="table-data">{{ board.title }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--    End of list dashboard   -->
```

I have tried the follow silly methods to see if it works:

1. `<br>` in html
2. `flex-direction: column` in css just for that specific `table-data` class

Is there anyway to do this? I am a beginner, any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: You could use a `<ul>` item to list the users as they are list vertically by default. That may be a cleaner way to do it. If you have to make a complex layout, CSS grid would work well.

Comment: @JayDev95 The css ```display:flex;``` overrides the ```<ul>``` and displays everything horizontally

Comment: `.table-data` is flex, you need to assign new class to apply `flex-direction: column` so something like `<div class="table-data new-class">{{ i }}</div>` `.new-class { flex-direction: column }`

Comment: @Libin - If the ul is the flex child then the li items will still appear vertically

Comment: @fmsthird tried that already. Didn't work. The flex property is inherited from the parent ```.table-row```

Comment: well, you might want to force it to display as block. `.new-class { display: block }`

Comment: Nope. Did work :(

Comment: @LibinThomas apply `!important`

Comment: Worked! It prints vertically. Thanks a ton @fmsthird

Comment: @fmsthird Can you post a separate answer with your suggestion so that I can mark it as answered? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a new class and apply `display: block;` to the user data div.
You might need to use `!important` to force apply the styles.